# How to trim spaces between words in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

How can i trim spaces between words in mongoose for my DB ?
Lets imagine a case `

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp', { useNewUrlParser: true });

const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
  }
});

const newTodo = new Todo({
  text: "   Cook     dinner   "
});

newTodo .save().then((doc) => {
  console.log('Saved todo', doc)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

If i run this code i will get a document in my db where the text value is`

```
"Cook     dinner"
```

But i would instead like to get

> "Cook dinner"

How can i get this kind of result just with mongoose ?

Comment: Which version of node, mongoose are you using?

Comment: Latest versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check `trim()` definition in the docs, it seems like you're trying to remove unwanted characters in the middle of the string, but `trim()` removes them only at the start and at the end of the string ([Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/#behavior))

I would suggest you to define a custom `setter`([doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options)) or `preSave`([doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)) hook for this and transform string using regex (if you want to remove only spaces): `str.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' )`